# Capture warning message in Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, try-catch, warnings, capture

I try to run the below and the user is already enabled for activesync, but set-casmailbox command always outputs "WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of (Name here) have been modified."
How do I capture that warning message in a variable? My try catch statement has no effect.

```
 **if($activesync -eq 'y') { 
                        try {
                        Set-CASMailbox -Identity $email -ActiveSyncEnabled $true -ErrorAction stop -WarningVariable wv
                        }
                        catch {
                              write-host " this is the ... $_" 
                              write-host " this is the ... $wv" 


                        } 
                        if($wv -like 'The command completed successfully but no settings of') {
                                Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow "active sync already enabled for 
                                $aduser "
                                $result += "active sync already enabled for $aduser "
                                }
                        $result += "`n Enabled active sync for $aduser " 
                        write-host " Enabled active synce for $aduser " 
                     }**
```

Comment: add `-ErrorAction Stop` to the end of the `Set-CASMailbox...` line. This will ensure that both terminating and non-terminating errors are directed to the `catch` block. Inside the catch block, the `$_` automatic variable will hold the exception object. Not the undefined `$ErrorMessage`. Also in there, use the `$wv` warning variable you have set, not the undefined `$WarningVariable`.

Comment: Theo, thank you I edit the code to be:  try {
                        Set-CASMailbox -Identity $email -ActiveSyncEnabled $true -ErrorAction stop -WarningVariable wv
                        }
                        catch {
                              write-host " this is the ... $_" 
                              write-host " this is the ... $wv" 
                                
                       
                        } but it still gives the same warning ouput as before.

Comment: If you use `-WarningVariable wv` then variable `$wv` is of `System.Collections.ArrayList` type but no its element contains the `WARNING:` prefix. Change `if($wv -like '…'` accordingly.

Comment: JosefZ - I changed it - and edit my original source code. Please see. But the warning variable is still not captured.

Comment: Are you running from console?
What happens if you say `$output = Set-CASMailbox -Identity $email -ActiveSyncEnabled $true -ErrorAction stop -WarningVariable wv`?
When you `write-host $output` does it output the warning?

Comment: Try outputting the `"$wv"` variable unconditionally. You should see both `WARNING: The command completed successfully but …` and `The command completed successfully but …`. Ensure that there is _no typo_ in your `-like` pattern  string. Use `*` wildcard there as `$wv -like 'The command completed successfully but no settings of*'`.

Comment: i ran this selected line from ISE only  $output = Set-CASMailbox -Identity $email -ActiveSyncEnabled $true -ErrorAction stop -WarningVariable wv . And when I do, it spits out the warning message regardless.